# Bubble data through class tree or unpack to get field?

Tags: java

Forgive me, I am an OOP novice and am currently coding out of my comfort zone at the moment. I  am unsure of the correct terminology to describe my situation so this is potentially a duplicate.

I designing a top trumps game as a hobby project and have come across a design choice.

I have The following classes:

```
  Game --> Deck<Card> --> Card<Stat> --> Stat
```

If I need Game to get a particular stat, should I create a card object, populate it with my desired card, then get the stat I need and assign the value. (Unpack)

OR Should I have a function to ask deck to get the correct Card which asks Card to get the correct Stat? (Bubble data)

My gut says the first is correct, and I think this comes under encapsulation, but this is fuzzy knowledge in my head.

I am being a little general here, but hope I have put in enough information for me question to be clear!

Comment: How are you picking the `Card` to get its `Stat` from? Is it based on the state of the `Deck` (ie the top card of the deck)?

Comment: Yes. Deck has a deal next card function which returns the card at index(0) and removes it from deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Stat` in question is a property of the the `Deck`, then you choose the second method, as this encapsulates the `Stat` and hides how it is stored.
example: `deck.getStat();`

If the stat is unrelated to the `Deck` itself then go with first.
example: `deck.getCard(i).getStat()`

Comment: I think I understand now. I didn't know you could 'chain' the functions like that. I thought I'd have to create a card, then get the card, then create a stat, get the stat to then get the value - which looks syntactically ugly and seemed unnecessary.